# Why create virtual host in development

Tags: php, apache, web-applications, wamp, virtualhost

There may many reasons. But I can find only these.

1. By creating vhost we maintain same file structure in the server.
2. We can have several server instance in one machine.

But are these really matter ? I doubt myself.

What is the difference between keep separate folder in localhost vs having separated vhost in localhost and deploying to the server.

Is there any other reasons to add(or are these not the reasons at all ?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're mimicking the production environment more closely; but this isn't a PHP specific coding question

Comment: Yes you are right not a PHP specific question, did i to get the php guys attention ;)
True about the production cost.But why local development when it doing with vhost ?

Comment: Personally I use virtual machines that mimic the intended production environment as exactly as possible in every way: if production uses vhosts, then my VM will use vhosts. This is often the case if you have both a front end and an API

Comment: So is it a good practice to have vhost all the time ? or any specialty  on API development ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your first point is the biggest reason.

If you have `http://localhost/devel` vs `http://devel.local`  your relative pathing can get all screwed up

If you had a developer who wanted to make a home link they may do `<a href="/">Home</a>`
This will redirect you to root folder on localhost and you wont end up where you should be

it is also a  separation of concerns. If you do a vhost you know you are only within that project. Another thing is if say you had a .htaccess file in localhost, it would affect settings in your project folder if you did not override the .htaccess in your project folder

Another reason is subdomains, you cannot really mimic subdomains with folders without using a .htaccess, it is much easier with vhosts

You always want to mimic production as closely as possible otherwise you will run into bugs on production that you will spend minutes/hours/days debugging that you might not have run into if you would have mimiced the environment  in the first place

Comment: Usually we are not going to have htaccess in localhost directly. Are we ? So what make it different to have just folders to each project that vhost ?. (I get the first point about the link ).. what am I missing here ...

Comment: I just listed off a couple examples, I coudl list off another twenty.  Hint: Even in your comment "Usually" and what happens incase if you do (by mistake), which changes a setting and you develop around that setting and now production doesn't have it?. What can go wrong eventually will

Comment: Please specify of can find any more. I'm trying wrap my head around.

Comment: I might have been exaggerating at 20 but another thing I can think of is wildcard subdomains, you would not be able to handle that properly on localhost (without setting up a special case .htaccess)

Comment: That is an excellent one... sub domain. I invite you to add it to your answer.